# Can typescript infer type based on a conditional expression & constant?

Tags: typescript

I'm curious how much 'effort' (for lack of a better term) Typescript puts into considering possible execution paths in order to determine a function's type.

For example, consider this code:

```
function getValue() {
    if (false) {
        return 'never this string';
    }

    return 42;
}
```

Because `false` is never `true`, "never this string" will never be returned, thus the function - it seems - should have type of "number".

However, when I add that type annotation (": number") to the function definition:

```
// test.ts
function getValue(): number {
    if (false) {
        return 'never this string';
    }

    return 42;
}
```

and compile it (`tsc test.ts`), I get this error:

```
test.ts:3:9 - error TS2322: Type '"never this string"' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

So my question, specifically, is:

Is it possible to get Typescript to consider that 'number' is the correct return type for `getValue`? (And, related, is it possible to thus have the compiler not complain that string cannot be assigned to a number?) Possibly also related: when the TS code is compiled, can the compiler be made to just remove the unreachable code and *then* run it's type evaluation?

Comment: Not sure dead code elimination is done by TS. Now that you've asked for it and I thought about it, I don't think it *should* be done. Consider a condition `if (someVar && alwaysFalse)` where `alwaysFalse` can be determined programmatically that it's always going to be false but it's very hard to track down manually. Now you will silently get different behaviour than what you'd (somewhat incorrectly) expect. This can in turn influence other stuff if you relied on type inference and though `getValue` returns `number | string` but now it only returns `number`, this can cause an effect elsewhere.

Comment: Imagine that function is in file1, used several times internally in file2, which is then used by file3. So you're there sitting in file3 and wonder why you get an error when you add a case for `typeof result == "string"`. You can *absolutely* get a warning for dead code but even other languages like Java will consider your case to be an error as they do count returns from dead branches.

Comment: You don't even need the `if` to create unreachable code; simplifying further to just `return "test"; return 42;` still gives a return type of `"test" | 42`. And that second `return` is, for sure, unreachable.

Comment: Do you compile with `--allowUnreachableCode` or something?  The example code is an error for me even without the `number` narrowing.

Comment: @jcalz thanks for pointing that out - for some reason when I run `tsc test.ts` the compiler (v.3.3) does not show an unreachable code error, but when I use `tsc -p .` it does (even though my tsconfig explicitly says `"allowUnreachableCode": false,`).

Comment: For a bit more context, I should say that I developed this question while trying to think of a way to have conditional types whose type depends on some constant boolean. The use case is changing a function type in response to toggling on some feature flag. 

Like, say you have a `getArea(shape)` and until now `shape` is of type `Square` but if `const supportCircles = true`, then the type of `shape` argument should be `Square | Circle`. 

But as @jcalz just pointed out, a problem with this idea is getting errors for unreachable code.

Answer (score -1):

The if-condition will not be explicitly false at compile-time, which is when TypeScript evaluates the return types. Because the expression which will evaluate the if-condition is determined at run-time, not at compile-time, hence we shouldn't expect TypeScript to assume the `getValue` function will never return a string type.

Comment: I'm not sure how `if(false)` can work differently at compile time and run time.

Comment: @VLAZ my response was more of making a point that `if(false)` is no different to `if(expression which evaluates to false at run-time)`, should we expect TypeScript to guess it's gonna evaluate to false to not throw a type error at compile time?

Comment: That was never the question, though. It's for code that can be determined to be dead at compile time. Yes, it's impossible for TypeScript to do dead branch elimination at runtime but that was never asked for.

Comment: Hi @hector101, thanks for the suggestion! :) I see your point about the fact that an `if` statement is executed at run time. However, there's an interesting point raised in a comment on my question: Typescript *is* actually able to determine that the code is "unreachable", which I believe implies the compiler does do a basic evaluation of the `if` statement at compile time. (But you are right that there are more complex expressions which could only be determined at run-time.)